# Why I get error at my service in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a service:

```js
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PingOnActionListenerService {
    removingListener = new EventEmitter();

    removeListener(): void {
        this.removingListener.emit();
    }
```

At component A I call the service:

```js
this._pingOnActionListenerService.removeListener();
```

At component B I want to listen to the service:

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        this._pingOnActionListenerService.removingListener.subscribe(this.deactivatelistener());
    }

    deactivatelistener() {
        window.removeEventListener('click', this.pingIfLastPingIsOld);
    }
```

When I run this code,
I get at the console the error message:

> core.js:1671 ERROR TypeError: generatorOrNext is not a function
>       at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3565)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
>       at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit (core.js:3537)
>       at **PingOnActionListenerService.push../src/app/core/services/ping-on-action/ping-on-action-listener.service.ts.PingOnActionListenerService.removeListener** (ping-on-action-listener.service.ts:19)
>       **at CatchSubscriber.selector** (logging-interceptor.ts:45)
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)

Comment: you need to type declare the event emitter, it probably wont solve the issue but you need it

Comment: `this.deactivatelistener()` returns undefined, so you're passing `undefined` to subscribe

Comment: `this._pingOnActionListenerService.removingListener.subscribe(this.deactivatelistener());` you are not calling the function `removingListener` here.

Comment: @callback `removingListener` is not a function, it's an `EventEmitter`

Comment: Also in `subscribe(this.deactivatelistener());` .. it should be `subscribe(this.deactivatelistener)` or `subscribe(() => this.deactivatelistener());`

Comment: @callback `someFn(this.cb)` does not act as expected.  If `this.cb` references `this` in some way, then it will not be the same `this` as where you're saying `this.cb`.  It will be the scope which eventually calls the callback.  Use the second option if `this.cb` references `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `EventEmitter` in Service, that is supposed to be used for component bindings and `@Output()` only. You should redesign that as `Subject/Observable`:

```
export class PingOnActionListenerService {
  _removingListener = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  removeListener(): void {
    this._removingListener.next(true);
  }

  get removeListener$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._removingListener.asObservable()
      .pipe(filter(val => val));
  }
}
```

And in component B use:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._pingOnActionListenerService.removeListener$
   .subscribe(() => {
     this.deactivatelistener();
   });
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe in component `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: private subscription: Subscription;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this._pingOnActionListenerService.removeListener$.subscribe(() => {
            this.deactivatelistener();
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

Answer (score 5):

While not directly relevant to the OP's question, I'm posting this in case it helps others.

The error `generatorOrNext is not a function`, can be caused by doing something similar to the below, where there is no callback passed to .subscribe().

```js
this.subject.valueChanges.subscribe(
    // (newVal) => console.log(newVal)
);
```

Comment: Is this not a pretty standard thing to do?  Some people use tap for side effects rather than doing anything in the subscribe